# Как передать параметры в подключенный скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скрипт подключается таким образом.

```
<div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/main.js">
     </script>
</div>
```

Таких подключений может быть несколько. Как передать индивидуальные параметры в каждый из скриптов. Глобальные переменные не подходят так-как они перетираются.
Думаю что можно делать так

```
src="http://example.com/main.js?param1=foo"
```

Но как теперь получить эти параметры в скрипте? То есть как узнать что эти параметры именно из того тега  что мне нужно?

Comment: "Таких подключений может быть несколько." - ?? Никак. Вместо этого нужно внятно описать, какую задачу Вы пытаетесь решить. И что это за такой скрипт, который подключается "несколько" раз.

Comment: можете просто в индекс файле вставить input hidden для каждого файла, и в JS просто получать их value

Comment: Вероятно, Вам нужно несколько раз вызвать с разными параметрами функцию из одного и того же js файла. Включать этот файл в страницу нужно, естественно, только один раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Трудно представить зачем вам такие заморочки, приведу пример на `jQuery`, если конечно оно допустима для задачи.

Один из способов используя `jQuery`, можно сделать так (результат вывожу в `JSON`)։

```js
var line = $("script[src*='/main.js']").attr('src').split('?')[1];
var data = $.parseJSON('{"'+ line.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g, '":"')+ '"}');
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/main.js?param1=foo&param2=foo2"></script>
```

Comment: есть еще такой вариант, через дата атрибуты: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904378/get-data-attribute-of-script-tag

Comment: @SultanovShamil да конечно, метод атрибутов тоже, часто используется, я постарался привести пример логики именно кода.